# Transferring data between controllers of different apps in Angular using a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to pass data from a front page form of a website to an application on the website where the user can fill out some additional information.

My problem is that every time I `console.log()` information after getting the object from the service, it is `undefined`.  I can `console.log()` when the object is set though, and this is correct.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?  I'm assuming it is because I think when the service gets injected, it creates a new instance of it.  How can I get the data to persist?

I have a form on the front page:

```
<div id="zipcodeForm" ng-app="form">
    <form name="zipcodeLookup" ng-controller="FormCtrl" novalidate="true" ng-submit="zipcodeLookup.$valid &amp;&amp; submitForm()">
        <div class="error" ng-show="zipcodeLookup.$dirty &amp;&amp; zipcodeLookup.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="zipcodeLookup.zipcode.$error.pattern || zipcodeLookup.zipcode.$error.required === true">Please enter a valid zip code.<br /></span>
            <span ng-show="zipcodeLookup.residence.$error.required === true">Please choose a residency type.</span>
        </div>
        Enter Zipcode:
        <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" required="true" ng-pattern="/^\d{{5}}(-\d{{4}})?$/" ng-model="zipcode" ng-model-options="{{debounce: 1000}}"/><br />
        <input type="radio" name="residence" value="residential" ng-model="residence" ng-required="!residence"/> Residential
        <input type="radio" name="residence" value="business" ng-model="residence" ng-required="!residence" /> Business
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

App Definition:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router','formService']);
var formApp = angular.module('form', ['formService']);
```

Form Controller:

```
formApp.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', 'FormService', function($scope, $element, formService) {

    $scope.zipcode = "";
    $scope.residence = "";

    $scope.submitForm = function() {

        var obj, object, data = $element.serializeArray();

        obj = {};

        for (object in data) {

            obj[data[object].name] = data[object].value;

        }

        formService.set(obj);

        window.location = '/application';

    };

}]);
```

Home Controller:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['FormService', function(formService) {

    var data = formService.get();

    console.log(data);

}]);
```

Service:

```
angular.module('formService', [])
    .factory('FormService', function() {

    var savedData = {};

    function set(data) {

        savedData = data;

    }

    function get() {

        return savedData;

    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are right, there are two instances created, one for each app definition. If you want to persist data between those two instances, the only choice you have is to read and write to a global variable that is defined outside of the service.

However, this is of course not recommended at all. I wonder why you have to work with two apps that are bootstrapped on one page (I assume at least that is the case). Is there no way to combine both apps into one? If so, I would go for that strategy.

Comment: The 2 apps are on separate pages, it's kind of a weird scenario.  Our CMS uses XSLT so on the homepage I have one template which has the form and then I have another page which is /application that uses another XSLT template that has the second app (which uses angular-ui routing).  So I don't really think there is a way to have them both in the same app, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: well then it is not an Angular limitation but is the nature of html documents. You could choose to persist data via local storage, a cookie or even pass information via the url. Each of these strategies has their limitations. The saver way is to persist the data on your web server either as session data or in a database.